# MySQL epoch time between two column epochs

Tags: mysql, between, epoch

Sorry if this has been asked but can't find anything. I have a table that has two epoch timestamps (one is start of a session, other is end of a session), I want to find if a variable is in between column x and column y. I've used between to see if a column is between two variables but can't really think of the syntax for the other way.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BETWEEN` should work for timestamps. However, there are a handful of other [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySQL that should be helpful. Check out `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: I probably should of just gone with my instincts. I always think I'm doing the wrong query with SQL